# Where is my own payment plugin in nopcommerce?

Tags: plugins, payment-gateway, nopcommerce

I'm trying to create a payment plugin in NopCommerce 3.30

I read "[How to write a plugin](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/77/how-to-write-a-nopcommerce-plugin.aspx)" and "[How to code my own payment method](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/76/how-to-code-my-own-payment-method.aspx)" links to create my plugin. I follow all of that steps to write my plugin. When I went to "Configuration->Payment->Payment Methods" page on admin panel, I saw only default payment plugins.

Could I ignore anything unconsciously?

Comment: Is your plugin getting copied to /Presentation/Nop.Web/Plugins/PLUGINNAME?  Does the version number in your description.txt match the version of NopCommerce that you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you specified right output path for your plugin (right click on plugin project -> Properties -> Build -> Output path). It should look like here: ....\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\YourPluginName\

And check that you specify right SupportedVersions for your plugin in Description.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your plugin has been reloaded and installed in /Admin/Plugin/List.

Answer (score 0):

This one caught me as well.

For prosperity - You need to first go to "Configuration->Plugins" from the Administration page, locate the plugin, and click the INSTALL button before it is available in the "Payment Modules" list.

(The documentation is not entirely clear and misses this step)